# Como cargar datos de mysql en un select de html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Estoy, intentando cargar datos desde mi base de datos en este select, la idea es insertar los datos del campo nombre de la tabla países de mi base de datos. hasta ahora probe  esto pero no se cargan.El archivo donde creo la base de datos esta en otra carpeta y cuando trato de importarlo al script me produce error, entonces no llega a ejecutarse la función. Si alguien me ayuda me harian un gran favor.

Codigo HTML:

```html
<div class="container mb-3">
    <select class="form-control" name="nacionalidad" id="nacionalidad"               disabled="disabled">
        <option selected>Elige un país...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Codigo JS:

```js
const pool = require('../database');

function cargar_paises() {
    const array = await pool.query('SELECT nombre FROM paises ORDER BY nombre');
    console.log(array)
    array.sort();
    for (let i in array) {
        document.getElementById('nacionalidad').innerHTML += "<option value='" + array[i] + "'>" + array[i] + "</option>";
    }
}

cargar_paises();
```

Comment: A mi me funciona a pelo: https://jsfiddle.net/v7n5qhr1/  (le he quitado el disabled porque sino no se muestra nada)

Comment: La función anda bien, el tema es que no me trae los datos de la base de datos!

Comment: Vale, pues de eso ni idea, lo que ese await da error de sintaxis si lo dejas ahi... ¿has probado de quitarlo?  ¿o de ponerle un async a la función? (un await sin async no hace nada e impide que el codigo javascript se ejecute bien)

Comment: Si me di cuenta despues y lo saque, ahí verifiqué que la función andaba correctamente, pero bueno me esta jodiendo el tema de la base de datos.

Comment: Mi experiencia manejando bases de datos directamente con javascript es cero patatero, no me parece nada seguro hacerlo, por eso no me interesa demasiado, aún así, lo que haces es una query, ¿pero eso te retorna un array seguro? ¿o un handler que luego debes recorrer como en php?

Comment: Claro en teoria me retorna un array. El archivo donde creo la base de datos esta en otra carpeta y cuando trato de importarlo al script me produce error, entonces no llega a ejecutarse la función. Yo uso la base de datos mysql workbench